# How create a time from a long value with java.sql.Time constructor

Tags: java, sql, time

I have a time in miliseconds, and I need to insert into a Postgresql data base. My problem is that when I use the constructor `java.sql.Time()`, I have the correct time but with one hour more!!

For example: if I have `503000 miliseconds`, the `new java.sql.Time(503000) = 01:08:23`, when the correct answer is `00:08:23`

My code only is:

```
new java.sql.Time(miliseconds);
```

What is the problem?? I read something about the Timezone. In this case, how I can resolved this??

I need to create a Date object with these miliseconds, and insert into my database.

> myObject.setDuration(new Time(duration)); // where setDuration has a
>   Date parameter

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible the value you are reading back from the TimeStamp is taking into difference in the TimeZone and/or daylight savings

Comment: Does the value get inserted into the database correctly?

Comment: Yes, the value is inserted correctly. And my machine has the spanish time.

Comment: @jjmartinez So perhaps the stored time is interpreted as GMT and the result you see has been converted to GMT+1. Can you explain how you retrieved the `01:08:23` value?

Comment: I have a System.out.println and also I'm watching in the database

Comment: The `toString()` of `java.sql.Time` is always in the current timezone, while a `long` value of milliseconds is always in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.sql.Time` is designed to provide the time based on the current time zone, for example...

```
Time ts = new Time(503000);
System.out.println(ts);
System.out.println(ts.getTime());
```

Outputs

```
10:08:23
503000
```

For me.

You can further test this by using a `SimpleDateFormat`....

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss Z");
System.out.println(sdf.format(ts));
```

Which outputs

```
10:08:23 +1000
```

Comment: The problem is that I need a Date value. I have a time in miliseconds and I have to insert into a Date object. Really, I only print to see what value is generating

Comment: Can I use other class to generate a Date object from a long (miliseconds) value???

Comment: Lots.  Consider using `Calendar` which will allow you to modify the properties of the date/time

Comment: I use, finally, Calendar: 
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTimeInMillis(duration);
cal.add(cal.HOUR, -1);
myObject.setDuration(new Time(cal.getTimeInMillis()));

Comment: I think you're missing the entire point. There is no need to adjust the time, as it's displaying the based on your local. java.sql.Time extends from java.util.Date,so you can use where Date is used. If you need the date component, you won't be able to use setTimeInMillis

Comment: I dont know why my first solution dont work. But with this solution I have in my data base the correct date.

Comment: Remember, the values are local contextual

Comment: Yeah, I know thanks to this thread. But the rare for me is that I store the date directly from the sentence new Time (myValueMiliseconds) and my database store the date according to my timezone. Is it correct??

Comment: Yes, I think the database is storing the time zone information along with the time value as well. What database are you using?

Comment: Postgresql with postgis

Comment: If the column is defined with "with time zone" them yes. Otherwise you'll need to test the result

Comment: Uhm, ok, i'll do it tomorrow. Thanks for all your comments!!!! I'll write here the type of the column, maybe it can be useful for somebody

Answer (score 0):

Your output `00:08:23` is based on your local timezone.

See my example here;

```
Time t1 = new java.sql.Time(503000);
System.out.println(t1); //print 06:38:23 - my local timezone


SimpleDateFormat sdfm = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
sdfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sdfm.format(t1));    //print 00:08:23 - GMT timezone
```